# How can I remove the timer of the preview screen?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, timecode

How can I remove timer from the lower center of the preview screen (circled in red) of adobe after effects?

[image]

Comment: AfterEffects does not natively have a timecode display at that place. It is most likely a part of your composition. If it is, you should be able to click on it and determine what layer or effect should be switched off.

Comment: Perhaps you have mistakenly enabled "Timecode effect", which must be disabled if you want to get rid of that burn-in window.  You might think this would be a toggle in a top-level menu, but you have to navigate to the effects window and disable it from there.